# What is a good antonym for "redundant" (engineering)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

What is a good antonym for redundant?

The definition I am looking to find an antonym for is:

> Source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/redundant)
>
> Redundant
>
> adjective
>
> 5. *Engineering.*
>    ...
>    d. (of a device, circuit, computer system, etc.) having excess or duplicate parts that can continue to perform in the event of malfunction of some of the parts.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(engineering)) has a page that uses this definition. Wikipedia defines this kind of redundancy as "duplication of critical components".

Used in a paragraph, "A software product can be installed redundantly or [*non-redundantly*]. The purpose of installing the product redundantly would be to allow for high availability. If one side goes down, then the other side immediately takes over. This is common practice in hardware and software industry."

I prefer a single word, but a phrase is also acceptable. I also prefer neutral or positive connotations. "Low availability" has negative connotations.

Comment: What is being negated, the duplication or the critical nature?  Duplication of non-critical parts?  Failure to duplicate critical parts?

Comment: @TimRomano You can't have one without the other. If you duplicate a critical component, then it is no longer critical. Either could fail, and the remaining one would take over. So to directly answer your question, both.

Comment: @TimRomano Just to put this into perspective, an antonym for "duplicate" is "unique". That wouldn't work here. An antonym for "critical" is "unnecessary". That wouldn't work either. I need an antonym for "duplication of critical components", held together like that.

Comment: Do you mean you want a word/phrase that means "take away duplicated redundant components thereby increasing criticality of remaining components", i.e. *remove redundancy*?

Comment: @MarvMills Nothing is being taken away or removed. I'm not looking for a verb. I'm looking for an adjective. I don't want to convey the message that it was or was not redundant in the past, or will or will not be in the future. I just want to describe the system as it is now: The system is not redundant.

Comment: An overall system *is* redundant if it is no longer required, but it *has* redundancy if it has the properties you describe. A component of the system can be described as redundant if it is part of a redundancy system. So you are looking for an adjective that describes the overall system as having no redundancy. It is clearly therefore a "point of failure" as suggested by Wayfaring Stranger, though whether it is a *single* point of failure is moot. I doubt there is a single word, just like there is no word that describes any system as not having seatbelts for aardvarks.

Comment: @MarvMills Okay? Your comment looks combative to me (the italics and the "clearly therefore"). I *like* Warfaring Stranger's answer, but you can't expect me to accept an answer only three hours after I wrote the question. I have a 100% acceptance rate on past questions (except for one that got closed). If the only point of your comment was to lobby for an answer, then you just need to be patient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24032/discussion-between-rainbolt-and-marv-mills).

Comment: @Rainbolt: Such phrases don't have antonyms.  If the system ought to have redundancies, but doesn't, you can simply say "The system *lacks* redundancy".  If there is no need for redundancy, you could say ""Redundancy is not necessary with this system, which has none".

Comment: @TimRomano That sounds like a reasonable viewpoint - one [shared by at least one other user](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/248015/72792). I strongly suggest you hover over the "add a comment" button and read the tooltip.

Comment: @Rainbolt: Your question is not very clear: words have antonyms; phrases do not.  You want  the antonym of `duplication of critical components' held together like that`. Your question is borderline gibberish.

Comment: @TimRomano Geez, I think "gibberish" is a little harsh! I edited the part you found to be unclear. Please ignore my prior comment where I misused the word "antonym". Does that look alright?

Comment: @Rainbolt: This is not meaningful: `A word or phrase that means the opposite of "duplication of critical components"`.   A phrase with the opposite meaning is "*no* duplication of critical components".  The opposite of "redundant" is "*not* redundant". It's like asking for the opposite of "in triplicate".

Comment: I would say "critical".

Comment: @TimRomano "No duplication of critical components" is *a* phrase. Is it the *best* phrase? Post your answer and let's put it to a vote.

Comment: @Rainbolt: answer added.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just negate the term with *non-* to form [non-redundant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonredundant) (or nonredundant). As with *redundant* itself, an engineering context directs the reader or hearer to understand the term in the engineering sense.

Wiktionary gives primacy to the closed spelling; OED offers only the hyphenated one, with examples but no definition (since defining the negation of *redundant* would be redundant).

Comment: As an engineer with may years of experience, I would vouch for this answer. But it would be better to include some examples in your answer. A simple Google search on phrases like "non-redundant design", "non-redundant electrical design", "non-redundant mechanical design", and "non-redundant systems", would provide many examples of its use. Comments don't provide enough room to link to them. (I understand this might be a circular argument, but, apart from my own experience, it does show that the term is widely used.)

Answer (score 16):

That missile is a [single point of failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure) device, which is why it's not [man rated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-rating_certification).

Comment: This is the answer (IMO).

Comment: "Single point of failure" has a negative connotation, though. "Non-redundant" systems are sometimes much better options when cost is a more important factor than availability. So even though they *are* are a "single point of failure" the resulting failure is minor or negligible. That being said, I don't have a better answer.

Comment: So... what is the antonym of "redundant"? I don't think you provided that. You have only given an attribute that a non-redundant device might have. (And even some redundant devices still suffer from single points of failure.)

Answer (score 6):

**single-instance**

For example

> Oracle ASM is a volume manager and a file system for Oracle database
>   files that supports **single-instance** Oracle Database and Oracle Real
>   Application Clusters (Oracle RAC) configurations.
> <sub>[Oracle Grid Infrastructure for a Standalone Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e48740/oraclerestart.htm#AXDBI999)</sub>

In your case

> A software product can be installed redundantly or as a
>   **single-instance**. The purpose of installing the product redundantly would be to allow for high availability. If one side goes down, then
>   the other side immediately takes over. This is common practice in
>   hardware and software industry.

Answer (score 4):

I think that depending on the context, you may want to avoid bothering with an antonym of "redundantly" altogether. Consider your example phrase: "A software product can be installed redundantly or non-redundantly".

You need the adjective "redundantly" to modify "installed" because by *default* things are not installed redundantly. So your phrase naturally sounds quite clunky.

Instead, consider the following phrasings:

- "A software product can be installed, with optional redundancy"
- "A software product can be installed alone or installed with redundancy"
- "A software product may be installed normally, or with redundancy"

Comment: I'd say "A software product can be installed with or without redundancy" over those options. Alternatively, if you're just trying to introduce the concept of redundancy and its purpose, just say "A software product can be installed redundantly" or "...with redundancy". Leave the alternative unstated, since I think the only way you could state it would be with "non-redundantly", which is exactly the word that would probably come to a reader's mind if they tried to fill in the blank.

Answer (score 2):

**Critical** or **Mission-critical** conveys the importance of the component while retaining the same sort of technical context.

Comment: If something is mission-critical it better be installed redundantly. I think you've misunderstood what "installed redundantly" means. It means that it is installed *with redundancy* (ie. duplicated components, multiple instances, etc) so that if *one* breaks there are identical components available to take over automatically. For example, redundant power supplies, or load-balanced servers.

Comment: @mfoy_, I think you've misunderstood how "mission critical" components are handed by normal people.  :-)  Yes, you **should** install redundant components and set up automatic failover, but lots of people go with the "buy something and assume it will never break" strategy even when they know it's a mission-critical component.

Comment: @Hellion but a component being "mission-critical" and "installed redundantly" are not directly related. One is not the opposite of the other; it is a whole other dimension.

Comment: @Mfoy: You are talking as an engineer, Hellion is addressing how us normals talk ;-) I am in no doubt that most of us misuse "redundant" and think it means "not necessary".  The usage of making you redundant = _you're fired_ may contribute to this.

Comment: *Critical* works quite well here, *mission critical* really doesn't.

Comment: In my former line of work, where a critical failure coupled with inadequate redundancy could mean loss of life / loss of billions of dollars, lots of redundancy was used on mission critical items. Criticality 1 items with no redundancy had to be granted waivers by people way high up the hierarchy. Things that weren't at all critical? They had little or no redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use clustered for plural and non-clustered for the singular. That is a common term in IT when dealing with server infrastructure.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster

Answer (score 1):

The term ***standalone*** is often used for this use case.

> Self-contained and usually independently operating: *a standalone computer terminal.*
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/standalone)</sub>

For example, [RedHat documents that](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Operations_Network/3.1/html/Dev_Writing_JON_Command-Line_Scripts/ex_cluster.html#addToCluster):

> A cluster does not directly manage either configuration properties or deployed content. However, if two EAP 6 *standalone* servers are in the JBoss ON inventory, then JBoss ON can work somewhat as a bridge, comparing the configuration and content deployments between servers and copying between them. That comparison is what the `addToCluster` function uses to add a *standalone* server to a cluster. It uses the configuration properties in an existing cluster member and copies them over to the *standalone* server.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what I can think of to describe 'non-redundancy' is either a commentary on the effect of the lack of redundancy, or a word that means the same thing but lacks the same connotation.

A few ideas are:

- Discrete
- Standalone
- Individual

And these could also be applied, depending on context:

- Fragile
- Choke-point
- Unique
- Unaided

And if you want to get tongue-in-cheek:

- Dundant
- Aredundant

Answer (score 0):

**Singly.**  You're only installing one of them, not several for fail-over.

Answer (score -1):

> Used in a paragraph, "A software product can be installed redundantly
>   or [non-redundantly]. The purpose of installing the product
>   redundantly would be to allow for high availability. If one side goes
>   down, then the other side immediately takes over. This is common
>   practice in hardware and software industry."

In mission-critical scenarios, best practice is to design for redundancy in order to eliminate *[single points of failure](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=single%20points%20of%20failure&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csingle%20points%20of%20failure%3B%2Cc0)*. If a component should fail, a redundant component can be brought online manually by the user—or automatically if the system is self-monitoring and self-correcting. In a simple "failover" strategy, the redundant component is kept on standby, whereas in a more complex system with real-time "load balancing" capabilities, an array of redundant components is put in place and the components share the load.